# Having two redux store in one application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a react-native app that contains two applications in it. These two parts have their own UI and state. When users open up the app want to sign up, they can select how they wanna use this application. 
I like to encapsulate state these two parts from each other.
My idea was to have two providers and render them conditionally, but don't know this is a good practice and have any edge cases or not.

```
const rule = 'first' // or 'second'

rule === 'first' ?
<Provider store={firstStore}>
    // first app related screens
</Provider>
: 
<Provider store={secondStore}>
    // second app related screens
</Provider>
```

Who can I encapsulate the state for these two parts perfectly?

Comment: Having two providers shown at once (where one is a child of another) would definitely cause problems.  Having one *or* the other isn't going to error but it feels like not a great design.  It makes your components very unpredictable because they don't know which store structure they are dealing with/

Comment: @LindaPaiste what is the solution? Can I have one Provider with conditionally passed store props?

Answer (score 0):

Separating UI and Data is a good idea. You can't have two providers though, you need to put these into 2 separate reducers. So, you can have something like this (code is just a snipped example, you'd replace with your own of course).

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import carousels from './dataCarouselsReducer';
import filterIntents from './filterIntents';
import generatedImages from './generatedImages';
import indexing from './indexing';
import { nlpIntentsReducer } from './nlpIntents';
import nullSpaceData from './nullSpaceData';
import { searchReducer } from './search';
import similarityIntents from './similarityFilterIntents';
import uiCarouselsReducer from './uiCarouselsReducer';
import user from './user';
import workflows from './workflows';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  data: {
    user,
    search: searchReducer,
    nullSpaceData,
    similarityIntents,
    carousels,
    indexing,
    generatedImages,
    workflows,
  },
  ui: {
    filterIntents,
    nlpIntents: nlpIntentsReducer,
    uiCarouselsReducer,
  },
});

export default rootReducer;
```